# Git_Bitbucket and Github with a same email address

Tags: git, github, ssh, bitbucket, email-address

I have accounts on Butbucket and Github with same email address, but usernames are different.
Should I generate the SSH keys or is there any easier guide to serve both plattform without problem?

I've tried this guide, but it didn't work for me.
https://gist.github.com/rosswd/e1afd2b0b0d515517eac

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SSH URLs, as your guide suggests, the username does not matter.
(It would matter for HTTPS URLs).

What matters is:

- [adding your first public key to your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)
- [provide your second public key to Bitbucket cloud](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-personal-ssh-keys-on-windows/#Provide-Bitbucket-Cloud-with-your-public-key)

That is how those respective remote Git repository hosting services (GitHub, Bitbucket Cloud) will know who you are.

That means you need to create two set of SSH keys:

```bash
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" 
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bb
```

Don't forget to use the actual `~/.ssh/config` `Host` entries for your SSH URLs:

```
git clone gh:meGH/MyGitHubRepository
git clone bb:meBB/MyBitbucketRepository
```

Comment: Thank you!! it helped me, especially the links from Github :)

Comment: @hellojun Great, well done! The link to GitHub does not include the `~/.ssh/config` part though, which is useful to have short manageable SSH URL.